Grey classes on developer.android.com Android API reference
When browsing the API reference on developer.android.com, many packages in "Android Platform" on the left side are grey, while others are in black text.
Example:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/dreams/package-summary
Neither package overview/summary nor the classes do have any deprecation warning, so the grey color must mean something different. What does it mean?


The greyed out packages mean they are not available to the API level you've selected from the dropdown. android.adservices were added in API level 34 while you've selected API level 16.
